Pst-Vectorian Ornaments---Are They Free to Use Commercially without Attribution?
I am planning on using some of the the ornaments found in the psvectorian package in a book I am typesetting with LaTeX.
I am under the impression that these vector images are free to use commercially. Nevertheless, I figured that I would check with the maintainer of the package---Patrick Fradin. But alas, CTAN does seem to provide contact information for maintainers of their packages.
QUESTION---
Am I free to use psvectorian vectors commercially; and if so, am I free do do so without attribution. I ask, because if I must attribute the source---which source would I list? CTAN? Patrick Fradin? or some other?
For example, Vintage Pack, Free Vectors is offering a FREE VECTOR PACK of---

"85 vintage ornaments, 110 illustrations and 18 decorative borders, all vectorized from the best antique sources. Use these free vectors for any commercial work, no strings attached :-)"

Likely, these vectors are, or include, the ones collected in the psvectorian package. (See the delineation of them.)
Any guidance someone may provide regarding the free use of vector images (such as psvectorian) obtained from LPPL CTAN packages in commercial works is appreciated.
I anticipate that the book I have alluded to will be published in the United States with later distribution to European markets. Thank you.

Legal questions are off topic but it is LPPL licenced so yes you can use in commercial contexts. But do not take legal advice from random people on the internet, ask your publisher's lawyer to read the licence.

@DavidCarlisle Without attribution?

As @DavidCarlisle says, legal advice is off-topic, so you need to go elsewhere to confirm the interpretation of the LPPL, but it is focussed on identification at point-of-use and does not contain any requirement for attribution, so a 'reasonable' conclusion could be that none is required

@JosephWright Many thanks for your helpful comment.

Contact details for package authors are generally included in package documentation. You can view this on CTAN or use texdoc <name of package> if the documentation is installed on your system.

@cfr I had tried clicking on "Patrick Fradin"; then "contact the author"---which gave me  https://ctan.org/help/contact-author---which gives no contact information.

@cfr However, thanks very much for your suggestion---for when I click on the documentation (which is in French), I found a link (https://www.vectorian.net) which leads me to the site which is offering the commercial free downloads.; from which is declared---"85 vintage ornaments, 110 illustrations and 18 decorative borders, all vectorized from the best antique sources. Use these free vectors for any commercial work, no strings attached :-)" I think I have my answer now. Thanks again. (Things such as this should not be this difficult :-)  )

@DDS The author's name in that PDF is also a link to an email address, so, if you do need to contact for some reason, you have that, too ;). Usually, the email is at the bottom of the first page and also often in the README, but this one is not quite standard.

@cfr Ah yes! A contact wizard appears when I click on the person's name. Thanks for pointing this out. I am learning a lot today.

@JosephWright Should this be closed due to the legal thing or answered or ...?

Note: see also https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament

Thank you for this link. I see that it in turn, links to vectorian.net.
